# Integral of $\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {{e^{a\cos (\theta - b) + c\cos (d - \theta )}}d\theta } $?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I know that the integral of

$\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {{e^{a\cos (\theta  - b))}}d\theta }  = 2\pi {I_0}(a)$

Where, ${I_0}(a)$ is the Modified bessel function of the first kind.

I am trying to find the integral of $\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {{e^{a\cos (\theta  - b) + c\cos (d - \theta )}}d\theta } $. Can I transform this integral into Bessel function or some known function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear combinations of cosines can be combined into a single cosine equation:

$$ a\cos(\theta-b) + c\cos(\theta-d) = f\cos(\theta-g) $$

Where:

$$ f = \sqrt{(a\cos(b)+c\cos(d))^2+(a\sin(b)+c\sin(d))^2}$$
$$ g = \arctan\left(\frac{a\sin(b)+c\sin(d)}{a\cos(b)+c\cos(d)}\right)$$

Hence you can just replace $a$ from the original integral by $f$ in the new integral.

Comment: Thank you for your useful insight.

Comment: Is it true if I have a form like $a\cos (\theta  - b) + c\cos (d - \theta ) + e\cos (b - d)$ where, the last term does not have $\theta $  included? Again thanks a lot.

Comment: No, you need a $\theta$ in each cosine term in order for them to be combined into a single cosine (except of course if b and d are such that cos(b-d) =0).